# Python for-loop separated by category

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm just beginning to get into Python for the Houdini modelling software.

What I want to do, is create a list/dictionary of sorts which contains "point coordinates" and a "building level value".  I then want to use a for loop for each set of point coordinates with matching level attributes.

What I have so far is this:

```
for point in geo.points():
    for i in range(-1,levels):
        if i == -1:
            pos = point.position()
        else:       
            pos = point.position() + hou.Vector3((0, level_height,0)) 
        coord = []
        coord.append(pos)
        for position in coord:
            point = geo.createPoint()
            point.setPosition(position)
            point.setAttribValue(pointlevel, i+1)
            point.setAttribValue(building, cluster)
```

What I actually want to do is:

```
for each buildinglevel:   
    do for loop for all points with that buildinglevel
```

My knowledge is limited but I know what I want to achieve, what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Your code example never defines `pointlevel`. Presumably you calculate that for each point?

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is called [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). `groupby()` will group an iterable by a key you give it, *provided the input is already sorted into such groups*.

```
from itertools import groupby

for pointlevel, points in groupby(geo.points(), key=pointlevel_of_point):
    for point in points:
        # do something with all points for this pointlevel.
```

where `pointlevel_of_point` is a function that returns the level of any point returned by `geo.points()`.

What `groupby()` does is give you the current return value of the `key` function, and a new iterable that is guaranteed to return all elements for which the `key` function return value does not change.

Comment: @MrE: That's what it says at the top. :-)